# How to wait for images to finish processing before reloading data of collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the new image picker API in iOS 14 and would like to be able to finish my for-loop processing of the images before calling my code at the bottom which updates my data sources and then finally reloads the data of the collection view. Currently, the code at the bottom gets called before the totalConversionsCompleted even hits 1.

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    var selectedImageDatas = [Data?](repeating: nil, count: results.count) // Awkwardly named, sure
    var totalConversionsCompleted = 0

    for (index, result) in results.enumerated() {
        result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { (url, error) in
            guard let url = url else {
                totalConversionsCompleted += 1
                return
            }

            let sourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary

            guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, sourceOptions) else {
                totalConversionsCompleted += 1
                return
            }

            let downsampleOptions = [
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
                kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 2_000,
            ] as CFDictionary

            guard let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, downsampleOptions) else {
                totalConversionsCompleted += 1
                return
            }

            let data = NSMutableData()

            guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else {
                totalConversionsCompleted += 1
                return
            }

            // Don't compress PNGs, they're too pretty
            let isPNG: Bool = {
                guard let utType = cgImage.utType else { return false }
                return (utType as String) == UTType.png.identifier
            }()

            let destinationProperties = [
                kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: isPNG ? 1.0 : 0.75
            ] as CFDictionary

            CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, destinationProperties)
            CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)

            selectedImageDatas[index] = data as Data
            totalConversionsCompleted += 1
        }
    }


    //I want to wait for the processing of images and then do this

    self.images.append(contentsOf: selectedImageDatas)

    RxBus.shared.post(event: Events.AlbumUpdated(images: self.images, indexPath: self.selectedIndexPath))

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: DispatchGroup, I’d suggest.

Comment: Where would I call leave() as if I call it after I increment the totalConversionsCompleted, the code at the bottom which I put in the wait: block gets called multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    for (index, result) in results.enumerated() {
        g.enter()
        result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { (url, error) in
            ...
            g.leave()
        }
    }
    g.notify(queue: .main) {
        // completed here
    }
```